# Chaining promises in parse - Swift

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is it possible to loop inside of a parse promise function? I’ve created this method but keep getting a compiler error. Basically I want to loop over a set of values in an array.

Parse.Cloud.define("getNews", function (request, response) {

```
var links = [
    "xxxxxxx?apikey=xxxxxxxx", 
    "xxxxxxx?apikey=xxxxxxxx"
];

 //    var newsJsonData = '{"results": []}';    
 //    var obj;
var count = '';

var promises = _.map(links, function (link) {


    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/" + link,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }

    }).then(function () {

       count += test  + '\n';
    });
});

Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){

    response.success(count);

}, function(){
    response.error("something went wrong");
});
```

});

Comment: What does not work in the posted code, do you get any errors?

Comment: I think you're rather looking for `Promise.when(promise).then(function(results) { var count = results.join("\n"); … })`

Comment: @Bergi the JSON being returned has / in them so my app fails, i can't seem to get rid of them

Comment: Please show us that returned JSON.

Comment: @bergi just snippet since its too long haha  `{"results":["{\"name\":\"creativebloq_top\",\"count\":10,\"frequency\":\"Manual `

Comment: Yeah, just a breakdown, thanks. But what's wrong with that (except that JSON strings within JSON are very odd)? How does your app fail? Can you please post the error and the code of that fail?

Comment: @Bergi hey i'm not currently at my computer right now but are you suggesting when working with this data in swift it shouldn't throw an error even if there's a slash within the JSON being returned

Comment: Yeah, it should not. (Btw, those are backslashes, not slashes). But it looks like `count` is actually multiple JSON expressions after each other (separated by line breaks), which is a syntax error indeed, but has nothing to do with (back)slashes.

Comment: @Bergi cool i'll give it a look tonight thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close.  The thing to realize is that the resolve function for the http request can become the resolve function of the collected promises (that is, of the `Promise.when()`).

The var arg parameters to that function will return an array of http responses corresponding to the requests (one response for the "a" request, and one for the "b").

```
// because it provides lots of useful stuff...
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.define("getNews", function (request, response) {
    var count = ["a", "b"];
    var promises = _.map(count, function(v) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({method: 'GET',
            url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
        });
    });
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {
        var httpResponses = _.toArray(arguments);
        var result = _.map(httpResponses, function(httpResponse) {
            // For now i'll return string but later will put the data i created
            return "string that will someday be a function  of httpResponse";
        });
        return result;
    }).then(function (result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Another way to do it, possibly more efficiently, is to chain a promise returning resolve function off of each individual http request.  It's a little harder to read, but if the action taken with the http result is another asynch action, and if that function relies on other system resources (distinct from httpRequest) then you can get more machines working for you in parallel like this...

```
    var promises = _.map(count, function(v) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({method: 'GET',
            url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
        }).then(function(httpResponse) {
            var promise = someNonHttp_PromiseReturningFunction(httpResponse);
            return promise;
        });
    });
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {
        // arguments here will be the resolutions of those
        // someNonHttp_... function promises
```

Comment: Hey dude tried you solution this morning but there seems to be an issue with passing a variable into the url as the parameter for the httprequest it breaks it for reason it only works when passing in a string as the parameter is there any way to pass a variable into this parameter

Comment: The url parameter must be a string, but that includes any expression that evaluates to a string.  So if you have `var foo = "http://www"; var bar = ".google.com/";`, you can certainly pass `url: foo + bar`.  Log whatever it is you're passing as url to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: i've updated my question with the new code which i'm using the problem is i have tried what you've suggested but where i am putting in the newsUr variable as the url in the httprequest l this is where the application is breaking on me